# breaking down xml into multiple xmls

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following xml, **xmlDoc** that looks like this:

```
<root>
<a>
 <Row>
</a>
<b>
 <Row>
</b>
<c>
 <Row>
</c>
</root>
```

I want each letter (a, b, c) to have an xml each. I want them to be assigned to these xmls **xmlA**, **xmlB**, **xmlC**.

so how do i do it in Javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
var $xml = $('<root><a><Row></a><b><Row></b><c><Row></c></root>');

$xml.find('*').each(
                 function(i,d){
                     if(d.firstChild)
                           d.innerHtml = '<p>WHATEVER</p>';
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do it in Javascript when there are languages designed for the job? Here's the solution in XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/root/*">
    <xsl:result-document href="xml{name()}.xml">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```